# Javascript library work with Meteor.js only when placed in the same directory as template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am new to Meteor.js and is trying to use a Javascript library HighCharts without pulling from Atmosphere. I am calling this Javascript library from a template helper in `client/views/main.js` to be displayed in `client/views/main.html`.

When I place all the library's files into `client/compatibility/highcharts`, I get a long bunch of errors in the browser Javascript console.

When I place all the files into `packages/highcharts`, I get a single clientside console error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'`

However it works only when I move only `highcharts.js` to `client/views`, it works perfectly.

Is this the correct way to use a downloaded Javascript library? It seems strange that one of the library's .js files must be in the same directory as the template file.

Comment: Please read this section in the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: Honestly, just use the Atmosphere package. That's the meteor way to do it. All you have to do is `mrt add highcharts` and you're golden. If you have an issue with the package author's code, you can clone it, and then put the cloned directory into your packages/ directory. If you put code directly into packages/ it will not work.

Comment: The author's code is minified... I have to edit the original source file and make it into a package or include it somehow into the Meteor app

Comment: Yeah, so just fork/clone and replace the js file with a non-minified one.

Answer (score 0):

- The only thing that goes to `packages` are well... packages. Only JS that is specially built using the packaging API can be placed there.
- `client/compatibility` are for scripts build the traditional way. They are not wrapped in a scope (IIFE I suppose) making them global, like ordinary scripts. However, they are loded *before* other client-side scripts. If this was a jQuery plugin, but you use Meteor's jQuery, there is a chance that you might be loading the plugin before the library. This will cause an error.

The usual way to do this is to use a Meteor-packaged version of your plugin, in this case, a [packaged Highcharts](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/highcharts). Otherwise, you just take a library and package as a meteor package. It isn't that hard actually.

If you ever wondered where to place what, there's an [unofficial FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files) that covers this.